# Linux remote run a scripts, screen hangs and never back to controls

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script in server. If I run it in server locally it is no problem.

```
<user@server> ~ % restart_forms A 
forms [A] is Restarting
<user@server> ~ %
```

However, if I run it remotely from client (another linux machine), it will be like this

```
<user@client> ~ % ssh server /path/restart_forms A
forms [A] is Restarting
```

Ths screen hangs and never back to controls; I have to use ctrl+c to kill the script each time then come back to controls.

I know this is probably related to stdin, stdout and stderr things. For now I have tried to run this background

```
<user@client> ~ % ssh server /path/restart_forms A &
```

Also tried

```
<user@client> ~ % ssh server /path/restart_forms A >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

All above fail and give the same issue. (I cannot create a screen to run for some business reasons)

Does anyone have any idea? Thank you

Update: When I try `ps -ef | grep restart_forms` in client, I can see this script is still running in client. It shouldn't be like this.

Comment: Does it actually hang or do you just not see a prompt again? If you hit enter when it is "hung" do you get a prompt again? What does `ps` say is running when it is "hung"?

Comment: See my update. The script is still running and never ended. And it still hangs when I hit enter.

Comment: Use `ps faxww` and see what is running at the bottom of the tree from that process when it is hung. I expect you will find something waiting for input or similar.

Comment: does `restart_forms` put itself in the background?  If so you wouldn't necessarily notice at the prompt, but your `ssh` could not terminate because it still has active child processes

Comment: @EricRenouf Ok. Seems like you are correct. How can I terminate ssh then?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run a script that doesn't terminate on its own and you want to run it over something like `ssh` it's best to run it in a `screen` or `tmux` session, so that it's terminal will be separate from the one `ssh` uses.  That way, `ssh` will be free to exit after invoking the script, and the script can continue as long as it likes.

To do that do something like the following:

```
ssh <user>@<host> screen -d -m restart_forms A
```

Comment: I am not sure Screen will work in our case because we need to input something after running the script (like type confirm "Y").

Comment: Well, you can either pipe `yes` into it if you're sure that's what you want, or you can connect to the screen session later by doing a `screen -ls` to see the running sessions and `screen -x <pid>` or give it `-S <name>` when you create it to do `screen -x <name>` to reconnect and have an interactive shell with that command still running, or you can look up (I have to run so can't show it right now) how to ssh in later and you can actually send keystrokes to an existing `screen` session without going interactive